# What is the difference between server snapshot and backup? (OVH)

Tags: backup, vps, snapshot, ovh

I have a VPS with OVH. There are two options in there, Automated Backup and Snapshot. What is the difference between both and which one should I enable so I don't lose the data and the configuration on the server. It took me quite some time to optimize my server so I don't want to go through that pain again. Plus, there's like 30GB of data uploaded. I don't want to risk that even.

Answer (score 1):

This explains it: https://www.ovh.com/world/vps/backup-vps.xml
So basically the automated backup is done automatically everyday and replicated in 3 different sites to ensure nothing is lost.
Snapshot seems like you have a max of two different snapshot and that you should do them yourself (like a VM snapshot).

Comment: Damn, so I have to take the snapshot myself every day or some interval? I have SSD VPS and it says, that automated backup is not available on this server. It means I have no option to keep backups.

Comment: @TalalMasood better double check with OVH support directly but yes this seems the idea. If it's too expensive try to take a snapshot every week, that should prevent big disasters